# VirtualDub AVI Compression

Tags: compression, avi

I am using VirtualDub to output compressed AVI files from input JPG files.  I choose

Full Processing Mode

as the video mode and

Cinepak Codec by Radius

I chose image quality of 100%, 50% and 10% but the output files are all the same size.  I would have expected the lower quality setting to produce smaller files.  Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cinepack is an horrible codec, and, as Roman said, it don't appears to really have an quality setting.

I suggest you to install the Xvid version 1.3.2 codec and try again. There are many tutorials on the internet on how to use it (although most of them are pre-2006/pre-x264). Here is a simple and up to date one: http://granjow.net/virtualdub-tutorial-installing.html

Also, if you are not using VirtualDub's filters and such, you should use "Fast Recompress" for the video. It is a little bit faster and higher quality, as it don't convert the color space of your picture from YV12 to RGB and then back to YV12.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, "Cinepak Codec by Radius" does not have a quality setting. At the very least the underlying VFW/ICM codec does not show a quality slider as an option. I suppose VirtualDub's setting is just ignored.